KAFKA ACL: WildCard Prefix in Principal name User
Scenario:

Clients connect to broker with SSL authentication, so the broker sees the subject in the certificate as Username. (CN=bucket1/user1,OU=Unknown,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown)

Configured ssl.principal.mapping.rules to change username to user1.bucket1.

Configured ACL for the clients whose username ends with bucket1 to produce message to the topic test-topic.

Here is the ACL configuration:
ResourcePattern(resourceType=TOPIC, name=test-topic, patternType=PREFIXED) (principal=User:.*?\.bucket1, host=*, operation=ALL, permissionType=ALLOW)

Now an authorized client is trying to produce message to test-topic and fails with Topic authorization error.


INFO Principal = User:user1.bucket1 is Denied Operation = Describe from host = 172.19.3.0 on resource = Topic:LITERAL:test-topic for request = Metadata with resourceRefCount = 1 (kafka.authorizer.logger)
Any inputs on how to achieve the wild card match in the Principal name User: ?
